# Azure : Deploy Angular(Front-End) & Node (Back-End) app without VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment, azure-deployment

I am new to Azure. I have never used azure. So don't mind if this is some silly question.

I have a client who also doesn't know much about deploying.

I have angular/node apps. He wants to host on Azure WITHOUT using a VM.

I am not sure about azure. So i don't know how to deploy without VM.

I know to deploy with RDP(Remote Desktop).

Can anyone help me with this. Is there a way to deploy angular & node app without VM?

Is there any specific documentation for  it? Which services will i need in Azure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi. Your answer helps deploying nodejs app although i have 2 apps. one id angular(front-end) and another nodejs(back-end).

Answer (score 2):

Except Azure VM, there are normally two ways to deploy Node.js app on Azure which include [App Service - Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web) and [Web Apps for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/), please see the links below to know these guides.

For deploying Node.js app on Azure Web Apps.

1. [Create a Node.js web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs)
2. [Tutorial: Build a Node.js and MongoDB web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-nodejs-mongodb-app)
3. To deploy the app with a [ZIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-zip) file, or via [FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp), [cloud sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-content-sync), or [deploy continuously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-continuous-deployment), or [from local Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git), etc. You can see more at the left sidebar of these pages.

For deploying Node.js app on Azure Web App for Containers， it's a simple way to deploy the app on Azure as similiar as on local docker.

1. [Create a Node.js web app in Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs)
2. [Build a Node.js and MongoDB web app in Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-nodejs-mongodb-app)
3. To deploy via [FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Fcontainers%2Ftoc.json), [cloud sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-content-sync?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Fcontainers%2Ftoc.json), or [deploy continuously](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ci-cd?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Fcontainers%2Ftoc.json), or [from local git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-local-git?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Fcontainers%2Ftoc.json), etc. Also, you can see more at the left sidebar of these pages.

Some important tools will help deploying easier.

1. Deploy via VSCode, you can refer to these offical documents for WebApp([App Services](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/app-service-extension/deploy-app)) or Container([Docker Images](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/docker-extension/deploy-container)).
2. To deploy on WebApp not Container, [Kudu](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/what-is-kudu-with-david-ebbo/) is a common tool for debuging and deployment. Meanwhile, for Node.js app, we need to use [iisnode](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode) to connect IIS as revese proxy for your app, and configure the `web.config` file via follow the [kudu wiki document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps). The [Kudu wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) is very useful and valuable for new to Azure.

There are more details for this topic which can not be listed one by one at here, but the above these are necessary. The offical [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/azure/?view=azure-node-latest) for Javascript developers is helpful for new to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Jay Gong posted a great answer for hosting on Azure. However, you might want to ask your client if s/he means s/he wants a micro services architecture. For more information on micro services, check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-overview-microservices).

The other viable option would be an App Service (which is an Azure service that manages deployment and abstracts a lot away, but there's a VM under the hood)? Without a VM for hosting, it would be rather difficult to do anything in the cloud on Azure - the only other option is local hosting, which would be without Azure. I would argue that it ruins the purpose of using cloud services, as it seems your client is confused.